# Using #define in C with no value

Tags: c, macros

If a `#define` is used with no value, like

```
#define COMMAND_SPI()
```

does it take value 0 by default?

Comment: What exactly stopped you from just running the preprocessor yourself and seeing what happens?

Comment: Note that you've defined a function-like macro, which means that `COMMAND_SPI` won't be expanded unless it's followed by a parenthesized argument list.

Comment: @KerrekSB one system's behaviour in one test case does not guarantee that all systems behave the same (or even that the same code behaves the same when re-run on the same system)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: On the other hand, observing even *one* conforming system *not* replacing the macro with `0` would have immediately destroyed the OP's hypothesis.

Answer (score 21):

No, it evaluates to nothing. Literally the symbol gets replaced with nothing.

However, once you have `#define FOO`, the preprocessor conditional `#ifdef FOO` will now be true.

Note also that in `gcc` and possibly other compilers, if you define a macro with `-DFOO` on the command line, that evaluates to `1` by default.

---

Since the OP updated his question to reference function-like macros, let's consider a small example.

```
#define FOO
#define BAR()


FOO
BAR
BAR()
```

This is not a valid `C` program, but the preprocessor does not care. 
If I compile this with `gcc -E Input.c`, I get a blank, followed by `BAR` followed by another blank. This is because the first and third expressions evaluate to nothingness, and the middle expression is not expanded because there are no `()` after it.

Comment: That last paragraph is compiler-specific; gcc behaves that way, but it's not specified by the language. For gcc and similar compilers, you can do the equivalent of `#define FOO` by passing `-DFOO=` on the command line.

Comment: @KeithThompson, Thanks for the caveat. I'll fold it into the answer.

Comment: Note that POSIX requires [`c99`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html) provide the `-D` behaviour: `-D name[=value]` _Define name as if by a C-language `#define` directive. If no `= value` is given, a value of 1 shall be used. The `-D` option has lower precedence than the `-U` option. That is, if name is used in both a `-U` and a `-D` option, name shall be undefined regardless of the order of the options. Additional implementation-defined names may be provided by the compiler. Implementations shall support at least 2048 bytes of `-D` definitions and 256 names._